How to track loss of multi-label MLP?
I am given binary data points of dimension 5,000. I am asked to perform machine learning predicting a binary vector of length 1k, where each position of the output is a class. The classes are not exclusive.
What I know about the class distribution:

positions with small index are more common
a sample can belong to several classes
each sample fulfills only a handful of class requirements (i.e. the output is "sparse")

How can I keep track of the loss in my ML model? I have used multi-layer perceptrons (pytorch) and cross-entropy loss (CE loss), but I find it hard to interpret the results. I assume CE loss is used when you have several classes, but only one is chosen at a time (multi-class classification).
Moreover, my prediction leads to vectors with about half the bits set, whereas I expect between 20 and 50 bits set, not more.
# An "example" data point:
point = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, ...,1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1] # length 5000
label = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...,0] # length 1000
# label has only 20-50 bits set


For multi-label classification problems with sparse outputs, a more suitable loss function is the BCEWithLogitsLoss. This loss function treats each class as an independent binary classification problem and computes the binary cross-entropy loss for each class, summing the losses across all classes.
You could implement something like this:
import torch.nn.functional as F

# these are raw logit outputs of the model, not after Sigmoid
logits = model(input_data)  # Shape: (batch_size, num_classes)

loss = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, target)

